# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory with python2.7/subprocess.py

Tags: python

I am trying to use a Python scrip that converts `Latex` to a `png`. The library is at https://github.com/cptdeadbones/pytex2png.

When I run the command `python examples.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./examples.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "./examples.py", line 11, in main
    pytex2png.convert("examples/"+file,"output/"+file+".png")
  File "/Users/kekearif/Desktop/pytex2png-master/pytex2png.py", line 44, in convert
    make_transparent_bg(output,display)
  File "/Users/kekearif/Desktop/pytex2png-master/pytex2png.py", line 31, in make_transparent_bg
    exe_command(command_line)
  File "/Users/kekearif/Desktop/pytex2png-master/pytex2png.py", line 11, in exe_command
    p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
```

What does this error mean? Is it an error in how the arguments are being passed?

From the source:

```
def exe_command(cmd, display=False):
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    if(display):
        p = subprocess.Popen(args)
    else:
        p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
```

Is there a mistake in the function above?

Comment: This file, `"examples/"+file` doesn't exist?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy the file is there

Comment: what is the OS you are using  ?

Comment: mac OS, Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have followed the Usage as describe here : [Usage](https://github.com/cptdeadbones/pytex2png#usage) which create Makefile.

Have you check the [Disclaimers](https://github.com/cptdeadbones/pytex2png#disclaimers) ?? It says the following :

> This code was devloped and tested on a Linux based system. I have no
>   idea if it will work on another system. If you have tested it on
>   another system, please let me know.